# Iterate through a Microsoft Word document to find and replace tables

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have some VBA code that iterates through a document to remove tables from a document. The following code works fine in VBA:

```
Set wrdDoc = ThisDocument
With wrdDoc
    For Each tbl In wrdDoc.Tables
        tbl.Select
        Selection.Delete
    Next tbl
End With
```

Unfortunately, I cannot easily translate this code to C#, presumably because there is a newer Range.Find method. Here are three things I tried, each failing.

First attempt (re-write of the VBA code):

```
foreach (var item in doc.Tables)
{
  item.Delete; //NOPE! No "Delete" function.
}
```

I tried this:

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(sourceFolderAndFile); //sourceFolderAndFile opens a standard word document.
var rng = doc.Tables;
foreach(var item in rng)
{
  item.Delete; //NOPE! No "Delete" function.
}
```

I also tried this:

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(sourceFolderAndFile); //sourceFolderAndFile opens a standard word document.
var rng = doc.Tables;
Range.Find.Execute(... //NOPE! No Range.Find available for the table collection.
...
```

Could someone please help me understand how I can use C# and Word Interop (Word 2013 and 2016) to iterate through a document, find a table, and then perform a function, like selecting it, deleting it, or replacing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure this answer out. With all the code samples online, I missed the need to create an app. For posterity, here is how I resolved the problem.

1. Make sure you have a Using statement, like this:

   using MsWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
2. Open the document and then work with the new msWord reference, the range, and the table. I provide a basic example below:

   ```
           //open the document.
           doc = app.Documents.Open(sourceFolderAndFile, ReadOnly: true, ConfirmConversions: false);

           //iterate through the tables and delete them.
           foreach (MsWord.Table table in doc.Tables)
           {
               //select the area where the table is located and delete it.
               MsWord.Range rng = table.Range;
               rng.SetRange(table.Range.End, table.Range.End);
               table.Delete();
           }

           //don't forget doc.close and app.quit to clean up memory.
   ```

You can use the Range (rng) to replace the table with other items, like text, images, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a backwards for loop? That's what you normally do when you want to delete items from a collection. Why are you using SetRange?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no need to do a backward loop as all the tables are found from start to end. As for the SetRange, that is the best way (as far as I can tell) to select the table and then delete it. If you have a better option, I am all ears :)